# Angular not working in an ajax response

Tags: angularjs, partial-views

ASP.NET MVC, AngularJs

I'm trying to use ajax to load some partials. I return the partial itself, from the controller, and I use $.html to load the partial. The problem is that the angular code inside the partial doesnt work. java script code that gets the partial.

```
 function get(a) {
    var div = $("#part");

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/part",
        type: "POST",
        data: { a: a },
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function (partial) {
        div.html(partial);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a directive for this ?

Comment: partial is data right ? if yes then this data is string or object ?

Comment: you shouldn't use jquery and Angularjs together.

Comment: I think Problem is in partial object which is return buy ajax success. not because of op using jquery inside angular  and i given +1 to @thegio because if we use angular then don't use jquery that is  true

Comment: @Gimmly can you send us what is inside partial object

Comment: thanks, I suggest switching the code to a classical $http service request.

Comment: @MartijnWelker my friend is working on the html/css part and im using angular to bind data to that, he doesnt have enough knowledge of angular and i dont think i can convert his html to directives without introducing hard-to-find-bugs.

Comment: @KevalBhatt it's a div, with angular logic. these are .cshtml files.

Comment: @Gimmly just implement your `get` function into a directive, don't use jQuery in your controller

Comment: thank you @KevalBhatt, this solves my problem, so you can post it and get your answer approved. my final question is can i ever use it like this? i mean get something angular with ajax,(either jQuery or $http.get promises) and then insert into dom?

Comment: looking for a badge

Comment: need to do it step by step

Comment: and this is the one that does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as we discourse in above comment yes you can append html in ajax success but there are some conditions if you directly assign your response object to .html or .append so it will not add anything but if your object is jquery object or any dom object then you can apply directly so it is depending on server side what you are sending in response.

Example:

Suppose my response has html string in **request.data** object

```
request.done(function (partial) {
    div.html(partial.data); //partial.data  has html string i.e "<div>test</div>"
});
```